# Practicing pronunciation via app

Tags: pronunciation, software

I'm wondering what ways there are too practice permission without a teacher, e.g. with software. I often will speak into pleco and Google translate to see if it can recognize my Chinese. I think this has helped me identify some errors in my pronunciation already.

Are there other methods? Does anyone have an opinion or info on how accurate pleco or google translate may be. I.e. if they correctly interpret my speech, how confidant can I be in my pronunciation?

Also, what about other apps such as Hello Chinese or Chinese Skill? They seem to be pretty forgiving with pronunciation, much more so than Google translate or pleco.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is use Middlebury. It allows you to speak into a device and it'll recognize your pronunciation and help with tones, etc. Also, on Middlebury, you can have an audio chat with a tutor if you wanted.